# Calling Function on an object Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php

Hello I have been trying to call a function on an object "person" multiple different ways in PHP to no success. There is a similar question on SO which has a solution that does not work for me. Calling any function with '->' operator results in error. Tested in multiple browsers so not a cache problem. Running PHP 5.6.30

Many thanks

```
<html>

<?php 

class Person
{

    public $Name;
    public $Surname;
    public $City;

    public function __construct( )
    {

        //$this->Name = $p1;
        //$this->Surname = $p2;
    }

    public function FullName()
    {

        echo "FULL NAME FUNCTION";

        //return $this->Name . " "  . $this->Surname;
    }
}



?>


<head>
    <title> Information Gathered </title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
echo "ALIVE" ;
    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];

        //echo "Hello". $userName . "</br>";
        //echo $surname . "</br>";
        //echo "from" . $city . "</br>";


        //$SubmitedPerson  = new Person($userName, $surname);

        $SubmitedPerson  = new Person;

        $m_instance = SubmitedPerson->instance();


        //SubmitedPerson::instance();
        //SubmitedPerson->FullName();


        //echo $fullname;

?>




</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing dollar sign **$** in front of SubmitedPerson.
Your code should look like this:

```
$SubmitedPerson  = new Person;
$SubmitedPerson->FullName();
```

Comment: Thank you, it was late night coding :)